# Get-ChildItem path without specifying the full path

Tags: powershell, path, get-childitem

So i am trying to get-childItem of a specific path.

my command look like this

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path fes\.policy -Recurse -Directory -Exclude ".*")
```

and the fullpath is something like this:

```
path 'C:\Users\(name)\(folder)\(folder)\(folder)\(folder)\governance\fes\.policy
```

and it works fine when I stand in the \governance\ folder and run the command. But when i am some where else it just add the parameter \fes.policy and says that the path not exsist

```
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path C:\Users\(name)\(folder)\(folder)\(folder)\(folder)\governance\src\Tests\fes\.policy'  because it does not exist.
```

which makes sense, but it just dont know how I get it to go back in directories and then put the \fes.policy on the path.

The start of the path is not always going to be the same, so I cant just put the whole path in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide either the *Fully-qualified path* (the path starting from the drive root starting with `C:`) or the relative path (the path from the current working directory). From what it sounds like, you are trying to use a relative path, which is useful when the folder structure is only partially guaranteed (e.g. `FolderA` in the example below will always exist, but it's placement under `C:` may differ from system to system).

`..` is a reserved directory "name" meaning the parent folder, similar to how `.` is used to represent the current folder. You will need to provide the relative path to the file using `..` if you are in a different branch of the directory structure than where  `fes/.policy` is located.

Since I don't know your full directory structure and only what you've provided let's take the following example:

- Current directory: `C:\Users\username\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC`
- Target file: `C:\Users\username\FolderA\governance\src\Tests\fes\.policy`

From `FolderC`, you should be able to locate the file with `Get-ChildItem` using the following path:

> **Note:** If any of the path has spaces you will want to wrap them in single or double quotes (the latter if you want to expand variables within the path string), or else escape the spaces with `` ` ``, though quoting is preferred.

```
Get-ChildItem ../../governance/src/Tests/fes/.policy
```

Since `..` represents the parent folder of the current directory, `../../` represents *two* parents up, and would put you in `FolderA`. From there you know `governance/` exists and you can craft the rest of the path as you need.